# Meteor.js template echo not working

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor, echo

I'm following a Meteor tutorial, following it step by step and I have run into two issues:

1) when I call the {{> message}} between {{#each messages}} and {{/each}}, my "check if it works" doesn't show up at all. When I call the {{> message}} anywhere else, my "check if it works" shows up!
    
    {{messages}}

```
<template name="messages">
<h3>message list</h3>
{{#each messages}}
    {{> message}} <!--echo of message template-->
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="message">
<h4>check if it works</h4> <!--didn't show up on page-->
<p>{{name}}: {{message}}</p> 
</template>
```

2) Also none of my Javascript works at all. 
I type in 'Messages.insert({ name: 'Eunice', message: 'hello world', time: 10})' to the console. and it is supposed to have Eunice: hello world pop up, sorted by time.
    Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');

```
if (Meteor.is_client){
  Template.messages.messages = function () {
    return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
  };
}
```

I'm usually a good de-bugger, so I don't know where I made a mistake. So I probably misunderstood how something works going from console to collections to templates. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if check is incorrect

```
if(Meteor.is_client) {

}
```

Should be

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed everything!